# PL/SQL Trigger to prevent insertion

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I need to write trigger in PL/SQL. I want insertion to be prevented when the condition is true.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SafeRent AFTER INSERT ON Rent
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.id_status IN (1,2) THEN
        DELETE FROM Rent WHERE id_rent = :NEW.id_rent;
    END IF;
END;
```

Explonation to the code: if id_status equals 1 or 2 I want insertion NOT to be done.

This is the trigger I wrote. It deletes (I suppose so, I have not tested it) the record after insertion if the condition is true.

Is there any way to prevent it before insertion?

I was thinking about rising exception in 'BEFORE INSERT' type trigger, is it a good solution?

PS: It must be trigger, I know it can be implemeted as Check constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use a `BEFORE INSERT` Trigger. 
And maybe use a `Raise_Application_Error()`. 
For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HelloWorld
BEFORE INSERT ON TableA
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        IF :NEW.id_status IN (1,2) THEN
                Raise_Application_Error (-20100, 'Something to post when raising error.');
        END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: you're right with the Raise_application, just a sidenote, you can fire it with before, or after insert. Works both ways.

Comment: Where did you get `-20343`?

Comment: @Matthew That is an example error code. This article shows you more info on that: https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/errors.htm#LNPLS99960, under the section 'RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR Procedure'. I edited it to something less completly randdom. :-)

Answer (score 5):

A trigger is the wrong way to do this.  Instead, use a `check` constraint:

```
alter table Rent add constraint chk_id_status check (id_status not in (1, 2));
```